# How do I get my Facebook login form to function?

Tags: html, css, facebook

So I have this beautiful looking Facebook login form but it doesn't actually function. It's practically just a hollow shell. Any help would be appreciated!

The login form:
http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/facebook-login-form

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Facebook Login Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.html" class="login">
  <h1>Facebook</h1>
  <input type="email" name="email" class="login-input" placeholder="Email Address" autofocus>
  <input type="password" name="password" class="login-input" placeholder="Password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login" class="login-submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by function? Is it not styled, does it log the user in?

Comment: It is styled but it does not log the user in.

Comment: You should refer to @Shadab-Shamsi's question. You would need some server side script that creates a session and the user would be logged in after submitting the login.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a backend to process login. The backend is the server side programming which would recieve values from login form and authenticate it using some database.
The common server side programming languages are PHP, Java, Python etc.

Comment: Are there any examples out there doing this with Facebook?

Comment: You can't use your login form to login into facebook. All you can do is to use it to login into your own server. One needs to integrate HTML code with server which only server's admin can do. Nobody else. HTML webpage is just an interface between user and server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Back end coding in the application that will actually take the credentials, namely username and password and do all the processing and log the user in. Using languages like PHP and ASP.NET etc.......

Comment: Are there any examples out there doing this with Facebook?

Comment: You cant access facebook servers for authentication

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just redirecting the page to the facebook login, it doesnt make sense to want to authenticate users on your domain in behalf of facebook. And since you dont habe administrative access to facebook database you wont be able to carry out this operation.

You can only just redirect to the facebook login page, easier